# how do I connect keyboard keys to functions In a game

Tags: javascript, html

Im trying to make a simple game with functions thre are loaded when the user enters a key on a keyboard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just add a event listener

```
window.addEventListener(event_type, event_handler, capture)
```

i.e.:

```
window.addEventListener("keypress", myFunc, false)
```

and you can use

```
function myFunc(e) {
    alert(e.keyCode)
}
```